# Deleting a profile request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am a newbie  trying to delete a profile but this message pops up in address bar

```
http://thexyz.com/the/delete.php?id=1>
```

Am I making any syntax mistake my code is as below-

```
<?php 
    $i=1; 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rw)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
            <td align="center">
                <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['Customer Id']; ?> "onclick="return chkstatus();">
                <img src="resources/images/icons/user_delete.png" width="16" height="16"/></a>delete
            </td>
```

Even delete is not working

My delete.php code is

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['username']=="");
        include_once('db.php');

    if( isset($_GET['del']) ) {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        $sql= "DELETE FROM opd WHERE Sno='$Sno'";
        $res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: add chkstatus() function code also.

Comment: @kumar_v can tell me what would be function code with edit above

Comment: @user2939942 did you check the below answers given by marcel?

Comment: ***NEVER*** use `GET` to change stuff on the server. Especially not deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `>` after `?>`

Your `<a href` should look like this:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo        
$row['Customer Id']; ?>" onclick="return chkstatus();">
```

Comment: it gives a blank page on editing this code http://thexyz.com/the/delete.php?id=1 also pl see my edit above

Comment: Because you check for $_GET['del'] and not for $_GET['id'] in delete.php

Comment: Are you sure you changed either the link to del=<?php... or the variable $_GET['del'] to $_GET['id']? It should work then. If the query fails there should be the mysql_error() printout. And what is $Sno? Shouldn't it be $id?

Comment: But the variable $Sno is never set! I think you mean Sno='$id' in your query. Now it is so: The query deletes the entries where Sno is empty. Then you will be redirected to index.php. You won't see an error, because the SQL Syntax is correct. Otherwise if you got a column named Id in the table then you might change the WHERE clause to Id='$id'

Comment: my column names are SNo CustomerId

Comment: OK then try the WHERE clause CustomerId = '$id' - maybe this is what you are searching for.

Comment: No pl its not fitting in.Let me check again.Leaving for now.

Comment: Sry, but I don't understand your problem. What you've got in delete.php is a variable set $_GET['id'] which contains the $row['Customer Id'] (surely not written together?)...and now you can delete the entry with the query $sql = "DELETE FROM opd WHERE CustomerId = '$id'";

Answer (score 0):

In your delete.php

```
if($_SESSION['username']==""); // IT will do nothing here
```

above code will not do anything because your have terminated statement with semicolon ;

You are passing id not del.

so $_GET['del'] should be changed as $_GET['id']

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM opd WHERE Sno='$Sno'";
```

changed to

```
 $sql= "DELETE FROM opd WHERE Sno='$id'";
```

Comment: @user2939942 then Query Will be

$sql= "DELETE FROM opd WHERE SNo='$id'";